# Accessing "Mapi32.dll" with C#

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport, istream

I am using VS 2008 C#
Windows Application.

I have this DLL Import I am trying to use.

```
[DllImport("Mapi32.dll", PreserveSig = true)]
private static extern void
WrapCompressedRTFStream(
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
UCOMIStream lpCompressedRTFStream,
uint ulflags,
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
out UCOMIStream lpUncompressedRTFStream
);

public const uint MAPI_MODIFY = 0x00000001;
public const uint STORE_UNCOMPRESSED_RTF = 0x00008000;
```

I have a compressed string that is in CompressedRFTFormat.

How do I pass the string into the WrapCompressedRTFStream?  I do not understand what the method is expecting.

I am trying to use it on a button.

RichText1.text = WrapCompressedRTFStream(_CompressedRichText.ToString(),something,somethingelse);

The first error I get is "cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.UCOMIStream"

I hope someone who understands this posts an answer that helps!

ok, so I end up in the same situation when I use the IStream.

```
[DllImport("Msmapi32.dll", PreserveSig = true)]
private static extern void WrapCompressedRTFStream(
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
    IStream lpCompressedRTFStream,
uint ulflags,
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
    out IStream lpUncompressedRTFStream
);
```

The real issue here is I do not understand what / how to deal with the input and output of this method.

Comment: You cant uncompress without knowing the compression algorithm

Comment: It is the microsoft outlook compressedRichText format.

Comment: @Midhat: that's the point of this function. Look at the in and out params.

Comment: I am looking at the in and out parameters, that is where I am having a problem.

Notice the:
How do I pass the string into the WrapCompressedRTFStream? I do not understand what the method is expecting.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I'm trying to do the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's not a good idea to use legacy native-code libraries & I would investigate some more time to find analogous code in .net

Try out *com interop* or *p-invoke .net* technologies to use legacy code.

Comment: I tried to use it with the com interop, but I failed to get it working.  Looking at the code on the link can you help me use it with interop?  (I do not want to learn C++ at this point.)  As for Analogous code in .net.  I have not found any as of yet.

Comment: May be this article will help:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rambab/outlookintegration10282006032802am/outlookintegration.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a native .NET method for doing this, a good approach would be to contain your approach in a Managed C++ wrapper.

What this will let you do is create C++ code to perform your work, while exposing a managed class to call the method. This may be more complicated since it will require you to learn Managed C++, but allows you to do any C++ work necessary, returning a .NET string containing your "answer".

Comment: well, that would be great, but like you said I would have to learn C++  (I am not ready to spend the time on that just yet)  I just need to figure out how to use the code on the link in my post within a C# windows form.

Answer (score 0):

UCOMIStream is deprecated, use ComTypes.Istream instead. Then look at [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream to System.IO.Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385684/system-runtime-interopservices-comtypes-istream-to-system-io-stream)

Comment: Any guidance on how to move strings in and out of the ISTREAM object?

Comment: IStream is not an (existing) object; it's an interface. You'll have to implement it in your own class.